# scrollend event not working in android titanium

Tags: android, ios, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

I need to create a cross platform for android and IOS but when I use the scrollend event it works fine for IOS but not in android. how can I resolve this situation so it works for both Operating systems?

```
scrollView.addEventListener('scrollend', function(e) {
        AddList();
});
```

I'm not using the alloy folder.

Answer (score 0):

Listen `scrollend` event and not `scrollEnd` : https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollView-event-scrollend

scrollEnd event has been deprecated and renamed scrollend (lower case).